# How to print every 6th row in data set in R using loops?

Tags: r

I have a data set with 5 columns and 60 rows. I am trying to print every 6th row of the entire data set using for() or while() loops. I don't want to use any other methods.

I have this code so far:

```
for (i in seq(from = 6, to = 60, by = 6)) { 
  print(i)
}
```

This prints every 6th row of column 1, but won't print the rest of the data set or column names. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: i is the row number, to get the rest of the dataset you could try `mydata[i,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are printing only the `i`, here we need to use the `i` as index.  Suppose if 'df1' is the dataset

```
for (i in seq(from = 6, to = nrow(df1), by = 6)) { 
   print(df1[i,])
  }
```

This `print` only on the console, suppose if we want to store those subset as a separate dataset

```
newdat <- df1[0,]
for (i in seq(from = 6, to = nrow(df1), by = 6)) { 
      newdat <- rbind(newdat, df1[i,])
  }

newdat
```

---

Using the inbuilt dataset 'mtcars'

```
newdat <- mtcars[0,]
for (i in seq(from = 6, to = nrow(mtcars), by = 6)) { 
      newdat <- rbind(newdat, mtcars[i,])
  }
```

If it needs to be a function

```
foo1 <- function(data, rn) {
    newdat <- data[0,]
    for (i in seq(from = rn, to = nrow(data), by = rn)) { 
      newdat <- rbind(newdat, data[i, rn])
      }
     return(newdat)
   }
```

---

Note that the subsetting index is vectorized.  So, we don't need any loop here

```
df1[seq(from = 6, to = nrow(df1), by = 6),]
```

Or using a logical recycling index

```
df1[rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), c(5, 1)),]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! How would I convert this into a function?

Comment: @AppleSauceBoss do you want the `for` loop to be a function or the vectorized one

Comment: @AppleSauceBoss updated with a funciton.  Hope it helps